# using parallel stream to call method already using parallel stream

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a method calling another method and both using parallel streams. I am not sure what is the consequence of doing that. I know that parallel stream using a fork join pool.

```
methodA()
{
list x;
list.parallelStream().forEach(a -> methodB(x));
}

methodB(list x)
{
x.parallelStream().forEach(y->something());
}
```

Basically method A is using parallelstream to call a method B which is using parallel stream.

thanks

Comment: It will work and in most cases, it won’t matter, how the CPU time is distributed over the actions. However, you might use something like `list.parallelStream().flatMap(List::stream).forEach(y->something());` instead.

Comment: Its that by default fork join pool has 3 threads available across the VM, so i was thinking as the three threads are already held up by method A, then method B execution might be blocked as there are no more threads to pick up the work.

Comment: No, the default fork join pool doesn’t have a fixed thread count, but a *target concurrency*, which matches the number of CPUs/cores. This may yield to three pool threads, if you have four cores, as the calling main thread will add to the concurrency as well. The key point is that all threads working on the execution of `methodA`’s operation will also contribute to the execution of `methodB`’s operation as that is part of the operation. If a thread ever has to wait for the completion of a stream operation, which runs in the same fork/join pool, it will be re-used for the parallel operation.